# /dev/urandom returning same value every time

Tags: c, random, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**EDIT I:** Windows subsystem for Linux.

---

## I bet I'm doing something wrong and/or really stupid.

```
// random_problems.c

#include <stdio.h>

main(){
  int rng;
  FILE * urnd = fopen("/dev/random", "r");
  read(urnd, &rng, 1);
  close(urnd);
  printf("%d\n", rng);
}
```

---

```
$ ./random_problems
32767
$ ./random_problems
32767
$ ./random_problems
32767
```

Same result every time.

**And yes, I checked: /dev/random is changing.** (Line breaks added)

```
[~] Connor >> head /dev/random -c 1
P
[~] Connor >> head /dev/random -c 1
m
```

I get the same problem with `/dev/urandom`.

I put the thing on loop with this little script:

```
echo "32767" > 32767; while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do ./random_problems > rng; diff -s rng 32767; done; rm rng 32767
```

(It even cleans up after itself!)

---

So, how stupid is this problem?

Comment: I bet the problem is *really* stupid.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266945/dev-random-returning-always-the-same-sequence

Comment: The first problem is that you aren't checking compilation errors or you're invoking your compiler in a mode where it compiles garbage without complaining. With GCC, use at least `gcc -O -Wall`. The second problem is that you aren't checking the return code from functions that can fail, such as `fopen` and `read`.

Comment: It's a short working example. I don't want to make it overcomplicated and confusing by doing all the error checking.

Comment: @Blacksilver this can't be migrated since you are blocked from asking on [so].

Comment: Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrr. I mean, look at my account! I have 300 rep! that should make up for the fact that I have two questions that are -2 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) with a `FILE` pointer, when it expects a file descriptor:

```
int urnd = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);
```

You’ll need to add some headers, and you might as well read as many bytes as will fit into your `int`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int rng;
  int urnd = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);
  read(urnd, &rng, sizeof(int));
  close(urnd);
  printf("%d\n", rng);
  return 0;
}
```

(You should also check for errors.)

Comment: Ty. I knew the problem was *really* stupid.